# List of public holidays by countries?

Tags: data-request, calendar

When working across country border it makes things easier to know in advance if people in a specific country are going to be on public holiday a certain day.

While some calendars application offer to import this information, is there an open list of public holidays per country (and ideally in icalendar format) available similar to what is available for time-zones ([Olson DB](ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/))?

Note: I'm aware of:

- countries specific sites like [opm.gov](http://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/snow-dismissal-procedures/federal-holidays#url=Overview)
- Also other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203708/is-there-a-comprehensive-api-or-json-xml-list-with-public-bank-holidays-worldwid)

But looking for an international list and thought that people on `Open Data` may have other data sources than listed above.

Comment: There is a GitHub Repo called workalender. It's hardly complete but you can always contribute! https://github.com/novapost/workalendar Getting all countries is a monumental task considering many countries use different calendars.

Comment: Also, public holidays are not always national: i.e. Switzerland http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Switzerland Some are even at the City level: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sechsel%C3%A4uten

Comment: Regarding local holidays - I just stumbled on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sechsel%C3%A4uten#Python_algorithm

Comment: There's [jollyday](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/), but I found their lists are largely incomplete or incorrect. Lists are organised by ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes in a non-standard XML format.  I'm currently assembling my own lists (in iCal format).

Comment: You can get the 'national holiday' from the CIA factbook (not all holidays, typically it's either their independance day or a royal birthday)

Comment: There is a GitHub Repository called [Nager.Date](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.Date) Current over 70 countries are supported and I hope there will be more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just came across Azure open dataset:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/open-datasets/catalog/public-holidays/

> Worldwide public holiday data sourced from [PyPI holidays](https://pypi.org/project/holidays/) package and Wikipedia, covering 38 countries or regions from 1970 to 2099.
> Each row indicates the holiday info for a specific date, country or region, and whether most people have paid time off.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i had been looking for!

Comment: I tested that dataset, it is far away from being complete.

Answer (score 12):

You could probably grab [Google's public calendars](http://gmailblog.blogspot.dk/2014/02/new-holiday-calendars.html). All of the calendars are public, but the URLs for them don't seem to be systematically listed anywhere. You would have to go into Google Calendar to pull the list of "interesting calendars".

Here's the one for the United States in several formats:

- [XML](https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic)
- [iCal](https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics)
- [Web interface](https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com)

Comment: What is the license?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I'm not sure. So, of course, this may not be truly open.

Comment: Calendars? That's is a great idea!

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [Nager.Date](https://github.com/nager/Nager.Date) project its supports over 100 countries (US, DE, FR, RU, UK, ...). The project is open source and available on GitHub.

Some data sources are available

- [WebApi](https://date.nager.at/Api) (Json)
- [CSV download](https://date.nager.at/PublicHoliday/Country/US/2019/CSV)

Answer (score 7):

I personally manage a site that lists the public holidays of every country of the world, both with long-term forecasts (some of our clients license more than 20 years into the future), and quasi real-time updates, to react when a country makes a last minute change (on average there is one or two such changes, somewhere in the world, everyday).

I won't mention which site it is, to avoid being spammed-out. In any case, which site it is is not relevant to what I am about to write.

All the forecasts are handled automatically by a library of code I have developed since 1989. I have also automated the search for last-minute updates. Yet, despite these 27 years of experience and automated code, and my ability to read news in 5 languages fluently, it takes me 4-5 hours per day, 7 days a week, 365 days a year, to make sure that I miss none of the daily and yearly changes to holidays and their rules, that occur all over the world.

My point ?

You will never find a reliable source of worldwide public holidays that is free. You'll find a few free sites that list the 10-15 "easy" countries. You'll find a few free sites that list more countries, but do not provide dates for non-western calendars. You'll mainly find free sites with lots of ads and cookies.

In some areas, there is still no such thing as a free lunch ;-)

Comment: Olivier, thanks for your insights. I happen to not share your point of view: as mentionned in my question, the Olson DB is a good counter example that it could exist. And the lack of existence is not a proof the impossibility of such an existence since a DB for timezone including changes exists...

Comment: With that kind of argument, one could predict that Wikipedia cannot exist... Yet it exists! Because came along crowdsourcing :)
And maintaining public holiday data sets is a good fit for crowdsourcing.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible that someone with the required competency in all of the world's calendar systems, with knowledge of the public holidays legislation of of all countries, and with an efficient system of alerts when holidays change, will one day decide to spend all his/her time updating such an online database for free. But, over the past 20 years, I have seen dozens of such projects start with great pomp and never get beyond the alpha or beta stage. Wikipedia gives good background on the holidays, but it rarely lists a specific date except for western calendar holidays.