# Worldwide holidays, and their names in the local dominant language

Tags: data-request, language, calendar

Might be slightly OT here but I'll give it a try since the topic is probably well known to many here:

We're looking for a database or system to get current and upcoming holidays by location, worldwide, and in english and **in each of the countries language**.

As in if there is a holiday on the first Sunday of April we would want to know that. I found various databases and small to large companies that export the data by year but most of them only offer the holiday names in English.

We would appreciate any idea about this because we're kinda stuck on this one ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of public holidays by countries?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1926/list-of-public-holidays-by-countries)

Comment: possibly but no - I would need not only the dates but also the names in the corresponding language. adding to this: the google calendar solution might work but as far as i can see they're all in english.

Comment: This question is ON-topic but the difficulty of making a worldwide holiday dataset precedes including local languages. FWIW, in Switzerland there are city and cantonal (regional) holidays, multiple languages, catholic or protestant holidays, etc...

Comment: not only for CH but also in DE and pretty much any country that has states are different types of holidays. but there are mostly country wide ones that count in all over the country and those should be available in the countries language. I mean I'm not asking "how hard is it to make a down to county level database of holidays", I'm asking for a world wide database of holidays for each country the countries holidays not per state necessary but also in the countries language.

the issue isn't that this doesn't exist - it doesn't exist completely and not translated. that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: I take it that things like https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q13959 do not suffice for your purposes (note list of languages at bottom of page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several are found here: http://holidays.kayaposoft.com/

A lot more are found here: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/projects/calendar/holidays/

Language is an issue though. Not sure what you want. In the case of e.g. Algeria would you want Arabic or French? Or in the case of Nigeria, would you want English or another of the [~500 languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_Nigeria).

Maybe the best would be to separate these steps:

1. Find all holidays, e.g. by crawling the [Wikipedia list of public holidays by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_public_holidays_by_country).
2. Translate into local langues

Comment: It may be easier to use the Wikipedia data dumps rather than crawl. https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps

Answer (score 1):

I think the Nager.Date API meets your requirements.

the model have both `localName` and `name`

https://date.nager.at/swagger/