# Where can I find holiday data for each country

Tags: data-request

I'm not sure this is the best place to ask the question.

I was wondering if anyone knows about any website that publishes the holiday dates for years in the past and in the future for each country.

I already went to [date and time](http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/) website but they only publish the lists up to 2020, but I need the holiday data up to 2040 for the european countries. (I downloaded these tables using a VBA macro)

I also need to know whether these holidays are fixed date or moving holidays.

Thank you

Comment: gcal, the GNU calendar, lists holidays through 2099 for many nations.

Comment: There's an answer here: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/6967/3840 for forecasted holidays

Comment: The best answer for open data on this is the one given to a similar question (flagged by @philshem above): http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1926/list-of-public-holidays-by-countries