# List of all UK bank holidays for the last 100 years

Tags: uk

I'm after a list of all bank holidays, ideally separate lists for England, Wales, Scotland, NI, that include Date, Bank Holiday name. I can find individual years' worth, or a decade or two, but I'm after a large data set for populating a data warehouse for analysis.
e.g.

- '30 May 2016', 'Spring bank holiday'
- '29 Aug 2016', 'Summer bank holiday'
- '26 Dec 2016', 'Boxing Day'
- '27 Dec 2016', 'Christmas Day (substitute day)'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of public holidays by countries?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1926/list-of-public-holidays-by-countries)

Comment: @Marcus D - can you check your requirements vs. the link posted above by Pluviophile please?

Comment: Yes it does thank you @Pluviophile. The Nager.date database (https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13215/10235) includes historic dates back a long way (pre to where I want to go), and the odd dates I know to be 'tweaked' in the UK are correctly 'tweaked' in this database. Happy to close this as a duplicate.